# How to pre-filter data before execute ElasticSearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm going to use MsSqlServer and Elastic together. MSSQL is the main DB and Elastic  is the search db.
My db struct is look like this:

- User (id, name, **companyId**) - 120k records
- Company (id, name) - 10k records
- Company_matrix (parent_company_id, child_company_Id) - 20k records
- Company_share_data (company_id, share_to_company_Id) - 50k records
- Product (id, name, **allow_to_be_shared**, **companyId**) - 1m records

I will create elastic index for product and company table to improve the search speed. A logged in user that have the companyId = X can see all products that have companyid = X, or all products of parent companies defined in **Company_matrix**, or all product shared by other companies from **Company_share_data** but allow_to_be_shared is not equal to false.

This query is very simple in SQL server, but a pain in a nosql db like elasticsearch. Is there the way to search the list of "available product ids" in sqlserver, then pass it to elasticsearch and mix them with the user's search conditions? Or any better idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood you want to see all the documents in Elasticsearch based on some criteria. If this is the case you can use [BoolQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) in Elasticsearch.

If this is a pain to you then the other way is to get the list of product Ids from your SQLQuery and use(pass) the Ids into [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) in Elasticsearch.

Hope this is helpful.